# Specify explicit fetch ref when doing "git svn init"

Tags: git, git-svn

When doing `git svn init`, the fetch ref will always be `:refs/remotes/git-svn`. This can be changed by hand, but in the hope of automating git as much as possible, it would be great if there was a command-line option that changes this value to something else.

E.g. running this:

```
git svn init url1 -R r1
```

populates `.git/config` with:

```
[svn-remote "r1"]
    url = url1
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

Is there an option to force the fetch line to something like:

```
[svn-remote "r1]
    url = url1
    fetch = :refs/remotes/branch1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the only way would be to write a script that calls `git svn init` and then `git config`.